# Make every nth observation an adjacent column

Tags: r

I have a data frame "df" that looks like this:

```
C1 (char)
X1
X2
X3
X4
X5
X6
X7
X8
X9
X10
X11
X12
...
X1200
```

What I need is a transformation that does this to it:

```
C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6   C7   C8   C9   C10   C11   C12
X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9   X10   X11   X12
X13  X14  X15  X16  X17  X18  X19  X20  X21  X22   X23   X24
X25  X26  X27  X28  X29  X30  X31  X32  X33  X34   X35   X36
etc...
```

In this instance every 12 observations become their own row of columns. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `matrix` to create a dataset with `n` columns (assuming that it is a multiple of n)

```
 as.data.frame(matrix(df1[["C1"]], ncol=12, byrow=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```